# Adding new Workflow State in TFS 2015.4 Agile Template - and missing in Kanban Board

Tags: tfs, agile, kanban

I am using TFS 2015.4, Agile template.  I want to alter my workflow states to include Analysis as an option.  I have modified the User Story WIT and ProcessConfiguration, Workflow nodes and valid states, etc.  I reuploaded the template successfully and set the new template to default.  All is well with regard to setting user story states.  However, on the Kanban board, I want to add a tab that maps to the newly added Analysis.  This new option is not showing up.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: This stack is for software development related questions. Please try to look for help on different stacks like DevOps.

Comment: @Zegar Stack Overflow is for questions about software development and **tools used by software developers**. There are thousands of TFS related questions and hundreds in the same vein as this one. It's absolutely on topic.

Comment: @J_NZ What do you mean by "tab"? Do you mean an additional column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [modify the process configuration to map new workflow states to metastates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/process-configuration-xml-element). Try the steps below:

1. Export ProcessConfiguration file:

`witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection /p:teamproject /f:C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProcessConfiguration.xml`

2. Modify the XML definition file. In your case, you should modify **RequirementBacklog** by adding your **Analysis** state:

`<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Stories" singularName="User Story" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" />
      <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.IterationPath" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Analysis" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </RequirementBacklog>`

3. Import ProcessConfiguration file:

`witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection /p:teamproject /f:C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProcessConfiguration.xml`

4. In this way, you can add a Column and choose **Analysis** state, it's similar to the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: This was it.  I was using the Power Tools to do the export/import.  Somehow that is different.  So when I used the command line, it worked!  Thanks!